# Find everything between tags which contains specific content using regex

Tags: regex

Input (Non-valid xml):

```
blabla<Val>Test2312x<End><Val>Nonazx<End><Val>Test<End><Val>Testazxcz<End><Val>asdsad<End>
```

Goal:

Extracting all tags content which contains "Test":

1231Test2312x

Test

Testazxcz

I have tried this regex:

```
<Val>.?Test.*?<End>
```

but it only captures the first occurrence without any letters before "Test".

Any ideas ?

Comment: Try this `<Val>(?:\d|\w)*Test(?:\d|\w)*<End>`.

Comment: `(?:<Val>)(.?Test.*?)(?:<End>)`

Comment: The problem with your regex is `.?` which means "any ONE symbol which is optional". Try this: `<Val>\w*?Test\w*?<End>`. Asterisk (*) means "zero or more word character (a-z, A-Z, 0-9, _)" and allows to match any number of characters before or after "Test" including zero characters.

Comment: @Inder Your regex is really close.. but it only captures the first occurrence

Answer (score 0):

Since you haven't mentioned which language you want to use so I am using `awk`:

```
awk -F"[><]" '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if($i ~ /Test/){print $i}}}' Input_file
```

Output will be as follows.

```
Test2312x
Test
Testazxcz
```